# TypeError: my_label_encoder() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to write one class with two def in python which helps me to do ONE_HOT ENCODING from scratch without using any library, without class my codes work and do ONE_HOT_ENCODING but with inside **class**, I faced a problem which I could not solve If anyone can help I will very appreciate it.
My Data is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5y1mucs3h93izp/car.csv?dl=0
'''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\car.csv', skiprows=1, delimiter=',', dtype='object', encoding='UTF-8')

class one_hot():
    def __init__(self,dataset = None ,column = None):
    
      self.dataset = dataset
      self.column = column

    def my_label_encoder( self,column):
       for index, label in enumerate(set(dataset[:, column])):
          dataset[dataset[:, column] == label, column] = index
      
    def one_hot_encoder(self,column):
      ncategory = np.max(dataset[:, column]) + 1
      print(ncategory)
      ohe = np.zeros((dataset.shape[0], ncategory))
      print(ohe)
      for index, category in enumerate(dataset[:, column]):
          print(index ,'index')
          print(category,'category')
          ohe[index, category] = 1
          print(ohe)
          a = pd.DataFrame(ohe)    
      return  a

   
e = one_hot()

b = e.my_label_encoder(dataset,1)

c = b.one_hot_encoder(dataset,1)
```

'''
And I get this Error :

```
TypeError: my_label_encoder() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I will be very happy if you can help me.

Comment: The code you posted contains indentation errors, please edit your post to have correct indentation

Comment: @AsafAmnony I hope is ok now ?

Answer (score 0):

my_label_encoder() function takes 2 arguments, one is self and apart from that only 1 other argument should be there.

self you are already giving('e') while calling it as **e**.my_label_encoder(dataset,1)

Pls. modify your code is

```
def my_label_encoder(self, dataset, column)
```

or else don't pass the dataset in while calling my_label_encoder(). Inside the my_label_encoder() you can refer it as self.dataset as you are using it in **init**, so you can pass while making the class object.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\car.csv', skiprows=1, delimiter=',', dtype='object', encoding='UTF-8')

class one_hot():
    def __init__(self,dataset = None ,column = None):
    
      self.dataset = dataset
      self.column = column

    def my_label_encoder( self,column):
       for index, label in enumerate(set(self.dataset[:, column])):
          self.dataset[self.dataset[:, column] == label, column] = index
      
    
e = one_hot(dataset)

b = e.my_label_encoder(1)
```

Comment: is it possible to share whole code? Because I have changed and that is not worked

Comment: Thank you, if it is possible could you please upvote my question.

Comment: is possible to share your contact address Linkedin or Gmail or ..